# how to use axios get method for every element in a very large array and save the result in json file without enobufs error?

Tags: express, axios

I have a very large array of length 17 thousand containing integer numbers. Now for every element in the array I want to make axios.get() request and save the response in a json file.

When I do this in the following way, I get enobuf error.
My Code:

```
for (const id of ids) {
    axios
      .get(`${BASE_URL}/${id}?json=1`)
      .then((response) => {
          fs.writeFileSync(res)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("error ", err);
      });
  }
```

My Error:

```
error  Error: connect ENOBUFS 69.64.69.90:443 - Local (undefined:undefined)
    at internalConnect (net.js:934:16)
    at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope (internal/async_hooks.js:452:18)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.emitLookup [as callback] (net.js:1077:9)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:73:8) {
  errno: -4060,
  code: 'ENOBUFS',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '69.64.69.90',
  port: 443,
```

I am realizing that maybe my approach is not convenient and efficient. Now my question is what my approach should be to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, each of the loop iterations in this code does not wait for the result of `axios` call.
Secord, you need to divide the whole large array into chunks of any reasonable chunk size, for instance by using `lodash.chunk` method if you wish to process some number of elements simultaneously.
Third, you definitely need to use asynchronous version of `fs.writeFileSync`, see [fs.Promises](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api)

```js
const chunks = _.chunk(ids, 10)
const writeResult = async (id) => {
  const res = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/${id}?json=1`)
  const fileName = id
  await fs.Promises.writeFile(fileName, res)
}
for (const chunk of chunks) {
  await Promise.all(chunk.map(x => writeResult(x))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your to the point explanation! It worked for me.

Comment: Hi, Your solution worked for me. I just had another question, is there any other way I can do this in more efficient way?what are the things I need to consider?

Comment: You definitely need some kind of a queue manager